# How can I store for loop results in dataframe in R

Tags: r, loops

I have checked previous answers regarding to my question but my question seems to be more complicated. The following is my loop:

```
for(i in 2:45)
{
    abs(meta1[,i]-median(meta1[,i], na.rm=T))/(mad(meta1[,i], constant 
= 1, na.rm=T)*1.483)
}
```

`meta1` is my data frame. I want to apply my for loop to column 2 to 45 (each is numeric vector) in my data frame. I want to store the resulting vectors in a new data frame. Could somebody point me out a direction? Thanks.

Comment: Looks like you are returning a vector of values.  Create a `list` i.e. `lst <- setNames(vector('list', 43), 2:45); for(i in 2:45) lst[[i]] <- abs(metal[,i], ...); do.call(cbind, lst)`

Answer (score 4):

Initialize a `list`, store the values in each iteration in the `list` elements and finally `cbind` it to create a `matrix`

```
lst <- setNames(vector('list', 43), 2:45)
for(i in 2:45)
{
 lst[[i]] <-  abs(meta1[,i]-median(meta1[,i], na.rm=T))/(mad(meta1[,i], 
                constant = 1, na.rm=T)*1.483)
 }

do.call(cbind, lst)
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not providing example data. That makes this guess work. But you could probably approach it like this:

```
meta2 <- meta1 
for(i in 2:45)
{
    meta2[,i] <- abs(meta1[,i]-median(meta1[,i], na.rm=T))/(mad(meta1[,i], constant = 1, na.rm=T)*1.483)
}
```